# C# Selenium Screenshot.SaveAsFile - Does Not Release Memory

Tags: c#, performance, selenium, memory-leaks

I have the following code for taking a screenshot of web page and saving it to file

```
Screenshot screenshot = ((ITakesScreenshot)WebDriver).GetScreenshot();
screenshot.SaveAsFile($"{fileFullName}.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

When debugging, in the VS Performace window I can see a memory jump of around 70-100MB (depending on the page size) when calling SaveAsFile() which does not release even when the method finishes executing.

Is there any way to force the Screenshot object to dispose?

Comment: My understanding of garbage collection is its non-deterministic just because the method has finished doesn't mean the memory will be re-allocated. As garbage collection is an relatively expensive process it only runs when it has to, if your system isn't under any memory pressure it may chose not to run or re-allocate that memory. Are you experiencing and performance issues because of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force garbage collection to happen by calling `GC.Collect`. However, you shouldn't do this for reasons [explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5zscb2d(v=vs.85).aspx).

.NET automatically handles freeing up memory for unused objects that aren't being referenced anymore. Garbage collection forces all threads to stop while its occurring so calling it often will have a toll on your application.